# How to fetch entire repository with GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm currently setting up GitLab CI/CD. We use GitVersion in our project, which throws the following error:

`/root/.nuget/packages/gitversiontask/5.3.7/build/GitVersionTask.targets(46,9): error : InvalidOperationException: Could not find a 'develop' or 'master' branch, neither locally nor remotely.`

According to [this blog](https://solvedblog.com/posts/could-not-find-a-develop-or-master-branch/) this happens, when the CI-server does not fetch the full repository (we have both a develop and a master branch, but I'm working on a different one). For Jenkins we solved this problem by expanding the checkout stage:

```
stage("Checkout") { gitlabCommitStatus(name: "Checkout") {
    
    // These are the normal checkout instructions
    cleanWs()
    checkout scm
    
    // This is the additional checkout to get all branches
    checkout([
      $class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/'+env.BRANCH_NAME]],
      extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, shallow: false, depth: 0, reference: '']],
      userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
    ])

    sh "git checkout ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    sh "git reset --hard origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
}}
```

I'm essentially looking for something equivalent to this for the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, runners download your code with a 'fetch' rather than a 'clone' for speed's sake, but it can be configured a number of ways. If you want all jobs in your project's pipeline to be cloned rather than fetched, you can change the default in your CI Settings:

[image: settings bar]
[image]

If you don't want all your jobs to clone since it's slower, you can change it in your .gitlab-ci.yml for your job:

```
my_job:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - ./deploy
```

You can read more about the GIT_STRATEGY variable here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy

Note: You can also set this variable to `none`, which is useful if you don't need the code but maybe an artifact created by a previous job. Using this, it won't checkout any code, but skip straight to your script.

Comment: Adding a +1 for `GIT_DEPTH: 0` to this answer.

Comment: Does not work, with and without `GIT_DEPTH: 0`. Or at least it doesn't solve the problem. If this is indeed pulling the entire repo the issue might be something entirely different, but I really have no idea what that could be.

Comment: If none of the "built-in" options will work, which it sounds like they won't, you can set the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable to `none` and do a full git clone in the script (or before_script) section. Something like 
```my_job:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    - git clone git@gitlab.com/my_org/my_project.git
  script:
    - ./deploy
```

Comment: @Adam git not found... I'm on a Docker executor. Do I need to install Git first?

Comment: There's a few options you can do. First, you could clone your repo in a separate job using a git image then upload the whole repo as an artifact that's downloaded on other jobs that need it (can control which need it with `dependencies` so jobs that don't need it don't get it). Second is to create your own image based on the image you need to use, and push the built image to docker hub, gitlab's built-in registry, etc. There might be more options but those are the two from the top of my head.

Comment: Updated docs link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in `script` manually:

```
script:
    - git fetch origin master
    - git diff master
```