# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline: how to run git diff between my current branch and main branch in the CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-diff

I wanna run in a pipeline step from gitlab ci/cd a command for getting all the files changed in the current branch comparing to main branch.
Unfortunately I couldn't find the proper reference for main branch.

[image]

I tried in many ways, instead of "HEAD origin" I tried a couple of versions like "HEAD..origin", "HEAD..main", "HEAD..origin/main", "..origin" etc.

Does anyone knows if it's possible to run git diff between my current branch and main branch directly in the ci pipeline from the remote repo?

Comment: Most probably this because CI did a [shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab-ci%5D+shallow). You need to unshallow it in [config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797810/7976758) or [fetch other branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854164/7976758).

Answer (score 0):

Do you run `git fetch` command to fetch your branches first in the pipeline job? you can then specify two specific branches from the output of git fetch, or HEAD with another fetched branch, also it makes sense to set a depth for the fetch